# AlertDialog.Builder vs class to extend AlertDialog - Application size

Tags: android, dialog, size

I am trying to figure out what is the best way to go about creating dialogs.  I can either create my own Dialog class (which, to me, is more clean and organized), or I can use AlertDialog.Builder (which would be done inline, and funky looking)... What are the positivies and negatives of either implementation? The only thing I can think of is application size...

Answer (score 2):

As a matter of personal choice, I would go with `AlertDialog.Builder`, if there is a routine at my disposal I wouldn't want to reinvent the wheel.

I cannoy say how the application size is different between the two, but if it is, I am sure it is not a drastic difference.  By how it seems you might have a preference as to create your own custom class that extends to `AlertDialog` so I would go in that direction.